# Grails: How to display a decodeBase64 String to GSP Page?

Tags: grails, base64

The base64 String is a tiff data, I used decodeBase64() to decode it but I don't know how to display it to a GSP page.

```
def convertBase64ToTiff(def base64String) { 

    def decodedData = []
    base64String.each {
        decodedData.add(it.decodeBase64())
    }
    displayTiffData(decodedData) 
}

def displayTiffData(def decodedData) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming displayTiffData is an action in a controller, you can render decoded data directly in the browser:

```
def convertBase64ToTiff(def base64String) { 

    def decodedData = []
    base64String.each {
        decodedData.add(it.decodeBase64())
    }
    displayTiffData(decodedData) 
}

def displayTiffData(def decodedData) {
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=decodedDataFilename")
    //You can try with text/plain or render decodedData to see if the decoding function is working ok
    response.contentType = 'image/tiff'  
    response.outputStream << decodedData 
    response.outputStream.flush() 
}
```